# apply strike of js to item within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to strike out the name of the item list and disable the checkbox once it's click? can I use ng-click or other check event?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yh02rAuH40XU0hB4eQO6?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is a version that uses AngularJS:

http://plnkr.co/edit/G29qWXYfzpmiIg6DZyKI?p=preview

First i setup the CSS class, then make a ng-model on the checkbox, so the state is saved.

It would help if you read some Angular Docs. On the [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) main Page is an example you should have stumbled upon, if you would dive just a little into AngularJS. So please read it.

Comment: simply bind with ng-model and the check state which return true or false? wow.. what if I want to hide the item when it's checked?

Comment: change the class of cause. `display: none` i get the feeling you did not read the example. they do a hide there as well. so go and read, not have others do the work for you.

Comment: I've read the example but I'm feeling lose. I know how to do things in css but I felt I've no control using ng-model. If it were jquery, I can add a check function to catch if it's checked, I can do this and that, like pass the id, send to the back using ajax etc. I hope you feel my pain and struggle

Comment: i had hard time too starting with angular, cause the approach is so different. I recommend taking a day to work through the lessons on [https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs](https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs) start page 9 and work your way down. That made me going with AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

You can do the strikethrough with pure CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label{ text-decoration: line-through; }
```

Will strike through the labels when a checkbox is checked.

I don't really see the point in disabling the checkbox when they're checked; isn't distinguishing between checked and unchecked ones enough?

Comment: I want not the css, I want to have control in the js side, I'm struggling with getting the right index when things r within ngrepeat.

Answer (score 1):

If fetching the index is all you want you may use $index

```
 <table>
<tbody ng:repeat="tasks in tasksList">
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="$index" ng-click="checkBoxClicked($index)"/>
<td>{{tasks}}</td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In the JS file you read the index

```
$scope.checkBoxClicked = function(taskIndex){
        alert(taskIndex); //the index gets prompted
    };
```